# Must click two times for Vue/Vuex to update array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

so I'm new to Vue/Vuex and I have completely no idea what I'm doing wrong here.
I have a method I call on click that looks like this:

```
Export (item) {
  this.exportObj = {
    start: this.dates[0],
    end: this.dates[1],
    userid: item.id,
  };

  this.getAllByFilter(this.exportObj);

  if (this.dateRangeText == "No dates seleceted") {
    this.disValue = true;
  } else {
    this.disValue = false;
  }

  if (this.exportData.events.length > 0) {
    this.exportData.events = [];
    console.log("Emptyed array because there was already data there!");
  } else {
    console.log("Well this was empty already :O");
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < this.allEvents.length; i++) {
    var timeStart = new Date(this.allEvents[i].start).getHours();
    var timeEnd = new Date(this.allEvents[i].end).getHours();
    var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart;

    this.exportData.events[i] = {
      start: this.allEvents[i].start,
      end: this.allEvents[i].end,
      title: this.allEvents[i].title,
      userid: this.allEvents[i].userId,
      hours: hourDiff,
    };
  }

  this.exportData.title = "Report for " + item.firstName + " " + item.lastName + " for dates in range " + this.dateRangeText;
  this.exportData.fileName = item.firstName + " " + item.lastName + " - " + this.dateRangeText;
  this.exportData.worksheetName = item.firstName + " " + item.lastName + " " + this.dateRangeText;
},
```

However, the array I'm sending the data to (exportData.events) doesn't populate before I click the button two times. I'm using a getter for allEvents, and the promise fullfilles. As you can see below the promise is fulfilled at the first time, but the data in the for loop doesn't get returned to the empty array. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

[image: Promise result]

Store:

```
const state = {
    events: []
};

    const actions = {
        getAllByFilter({ commit }, exportObj) {
        calendarService.getAllByFilter(exportObj)
            .then(
                events => commit('getAllSuccess', events),
                error => commit('getAllFailure', error)
            );
        },
    };
    
    const getters = {
    allEvents: state => state.events
    };
    
    const mutations = {
    getAllSuccess(state, events) {
        state.events = events;
        },
    };
    
    export const calendar = {
        namespaced: true,
        state,
        actions,
        mutations,
        getters
    };
```

Comment: Send action, mutation, and state of your store. Filling exportData.event depends on allEvent getters. where do you update the underlying data?

Comment: @Mr. Hi, thanks for the comment! Do you believe the store to be the case? I've added it to the code now.

Comment: As a workaround I can use the state (events: (state) => state.calendar.events). However, this wont let me do stuff with the state like the getter does (in the methods).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
this.getAllByFilter(this.exportObj);
```

The Promise in this action was not handled anywhere. Return your Promise then await it.

```
const actions = {
    getAllByFilter({ commit }, exportObj) {
    return calendarService.getAllByFilter(exportObj)
        .then(
            events => commit('getAllSuccess', events),
            error => commit('getAllFailure', error)
        );
    },
};
```

Revise your Export method to:

```
async Export (item) {
  this.exportObj = {
    start: this.dates[0],
    end: this.dates[1],
    userid: item.id,
  };

  await this.getAllByFilter(this.exportObj);
  ....
```

Show a progress bar, loading dialog, or disable the button until the Export method finishes its job.

Comment: Appreciate it, but not the answer here.. The promise is resolved and handled in the calendarService.getAllByFilter function, so there's no need to return it in the store. I do believe this to be linked with "Vue reactivity rules", as I can change the code in the mutation and it will return the right result. I also usually handle the promise with a request status, but haven't got so far yet because I was trying to debug this... I don't see the need for making the method async?

Comment: You need to await for getAllByFilter method because the rest of your code depends on it.